# How to create different filters for the same files in different projects?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

I have this file structure:

```
    My Solution(dir)
          +-- CMakeLists.txt
          +-- MainProject(dir)
              +-- File1.cpp
              +-- File1.h
              +-- File2.cpp
              +-- File2.h
              +-- Subdirectory(dir)
                  +-- File1.cpp
                  +-- File1.h
                  +-- File2.cpp
                  +-- File2.h
          +-- TestMainProject(dir)
              +-- TestFile1.cpp
              +-- TestFile2.cpp
              +-- Subdirectory(dir)
                  +-- TestFile1.cpp
                  +-- TestFile2.cpp
```

For the `MainProject` I'd like to include all files from the `MainProject` folder with filters following the folder structure.
For the `TestMainProject` I'd like to include all files from the `MainProject` folder with filters following the folder structure but also put all these files under the `MainProject` filter. Same for the `TestMainProject` directory: put all files under the `TestMainProject` filter and follow the folder structure.

I want to achieve this:
[image]

So I wrote this code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project("CMake Subdirectories Filters Example")

set(main_project_name "MainProject")
set(main_project_path "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${main_project_name}")
file(GLOB_RECURSE main_project_files "${main_project_path}/*.h" "${main_project_path}/*.cpp")
add_executable(${main_project_name} ${main_project_files})
source_group(TREE "${main_project_path}/" FILES ${main_project_files})

function(group_source_files_into_filter_with_folder_structure files_list project_path filter_to_put_into)
    foreach(file_path IN LISTS files_list)
        get_filename_component(file_directory_path "${file_path}" DIRECTORY)
        string(REPLACE ${project_path} ${filter_to_put_into} file_path_msvc_relative "${file_directory_path}")
        string(REPLACE "/" "\\" source_path_msvc "${file_path_msvc_relative}")
        source_group("${source_path_msvc}" FILES "${file_path}")
    endforeach()
endfunction()

set(test_main_project_name "TestMainProject")
set(test_main_project_path "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${test_main_project_name}")
file(GLOB_RECURSE test_main_project_files "${test_main_project_path}/*.h" "${test_main_project_path}/*.cpp")
add_executable(${test_main_project_name} ${main_project_files} ${test_main_project_files})
group_source_files_into_filter_with_folder_structure("${main_project_files}" "${main_project_path}" "${main_project_name}")
group_source_files_into_filter_with_folder_structure("${test_main_project_files}" "${test_main_project_path}" "${test_main_project_name}")
```

It almost does the job:
[image]

It does create filters as I want it to for the `TestMainProject`: it creates the additional `TestMainProject` filter for the `TestMainProject` folder and additional `MainProject` filter for the `MainProject` folder.

The problem is that it also creates additional `MainProject` filter for the `MainProject` folder in the `MainProject` folder:
[image]

And here's what I'd like to achieve:
[image]

See how there is no `MainProject` filter in the `MainProject` project.

Is there a way to do what I would like to do? Feels like I hit a limit of CMake and there's no way because, apparently, source_group is global and it creates the group for the files for all projects.

Comment: If you're building some sources as part of 2 separate projects without any different compile options, shouldn't you be moving those files to a static lib (or object lib)? Also how do the additional sources influence the resulting program? In most cases logic from in additional source files needs to be explicitly used in the source containing the main or in logic used by the main, so if `main_project_files` alone do compile, how do the additional source files `test_main_project_files` make a difference?

Comment: _shouldn't you be moving those files to a static lib (or object lib)?_ No, this is done to be able to do link seam(linker substitution) technique to be able to mock global functions to be able to test modules that do system calls. This method is described in the _Modern C++ Programming with Test-Driven Development: Code Better, Sleep Better_ by Jeff Langr and _Working Effectively with Legacy Code_ by Michael Feathers. Here's the chapter from the Michael Feather's book about it: https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417&seqNum=3

Comment: _Also how do the additional sources influence the resulting program?_ Just as any normal .h and .cpp files from a single source: they're just a bunch of files in different folders.

Comment: _Also how do the additional sources influence the resulting program?_ In this case the files in the `TestMainProject` are test files for the files inside the `MainProject` folder. And so the `TestMainProject` files include the headers from the `MainProject` folder and test the source files. But the `TestMainProject` project does not reference the `MainProject` project, it only uses .h and .cpp files, and compiles its own object files and the executable. This allows to not link system libraries that the main project links and provide my own mock implementations for testing in the test project.

Comment: @273K don't edit other people's questions that are asked following the "how to ask good question" suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Specifically, see the: **If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself.** part. Which is exactly what I did in my question.

Comment: Whoever closed the question: what kind of details or clarity do you need? It lists all the code, includes all the files and everything. There is no any details or clarity to add here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help over on the [CMake forum](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/how-to-create-different-filters-for-the-same-files-in-different-projects/6360):

I put CMakeLists.txt in sub-folders and got this in the end:

CMakeLists.txt in the root directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project("CMake Subdirectories Filters Example")

set(main_project_name "MainProject")
set(main_project_path "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${main_project_name}")
file(GLOB_RECURSE main_project_files "${main_project_path}/*.h" "${main_project_path}/*.cpp")

add_subdirectory(MainProject)
add_subdirectory(TestMainProject)
```

CMakeLists.txt in the `MainProject` folder:

```
add_executable(${main_project_name} ${main_project_files})
source_group(TREE "${main_project_path}/" FILES ${main_project_files})
```

CMakeLists.txt in the `TestMainProject` folder:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(test_main_project_name "TestMainProject")
set(test_main_project_path "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${test_main_project_name}")
file(GLOB_RECURSE test_main_project_files "${test_main_project_path}/*.h" "${test_main_project_path}/*.cpp")
add_executable(${test_main_project_name} ${main_project_files} ${test_main_project_files})
source_group(TREE "${main_project_path}/" PREFIX "${main_project_name}" FILES ${main_project_files})
source_group(TREE "${test_main_project_path}/" PREFIX "${test_main_project_name}" FILES ${test_main_project_files})
```

Now it generates the correct filters, just as I wanted:
[image]